# Is it possible to compute the mixed Hodge structure of a unramified covering space?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, hodge-theory

Assume that we know the mixed Hodge structure of a complex manifold $X$. Is it possible to compute the mixed Hodge structure of unramified covering $Y$ of $X$ if we know the deck transformation of the covering?

This is possible if we pass it to the Euler characteristics. If this is not true in general, what information do we need to compute the mixed Hodge structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $p\colon Y\to X$ is the projection, the image $p_*\mathcal{O}_Y$ splits into $\deg p$ line bundles $\mathcal{L}_i$, roughly corresponding to the eigenvalues of $p$. Then the Hodge structure upstairs (split by the eigenvalues) is formed by $H^p(X;\Omega^q(X)\otimes\mathcal{L}_i)$; you need these data.

If you want mixed Hodge structure (singular or quasi-projective varieties), you should replace $\Omega^q$ with the appropriate sheaves; the rest remains unchanged.

David's remark: of course, this works if the covering is Galois and the deck translation group is abelian; in the non-abelian case, you have more complicated vector bundles corresponding to the irreducible representations of the deck translation, and for an irregular (= non-Galois) covering this seems to be becoming wilds: all one can say is that the higher direct images vanish and you can compute the cohomology downstairs.

Just one last remark: if the deck translation is cyclic, say, $\mathbb{Z}_n$, then a covering is pretty much the same as an $n$-torsion line bundle $\mathcal{L}$, and then one has $\mathcal{L}_i=\mathcal{L}^{\otimes i}$, so it's all pretty straightforward. Essentially this goes back (at least) to Zariski (cyclic multiple planes), although he didn't use this language (as i hadn't been developed at the time).

Comment: Just to check, line bundles when the deck group is commutative, but in general vector bundles correponding to irreps of the deck group, right?

Comment: Yes, sure, sorry; I will edit this. Otherwise the problem becomes completely transcendental :)

Comment: I don't think it is wild for a non-Galois covering at all! Let $Z \to Y \to X$ be the Galois closure, with Galois group $G$, and with $H \subset G$ the stabilizer of $Y$. Then $\pi_{\ast}(\mathcal{O}(Y))$ injects into $\pi_{\ast}(\mathcal{O}(Z))$ as the $H$-invariants. You can still break the problem up over irreps of $G$.

Comment: You're assuming $X$ compact here, right?

Comment: @DanPetersen No, why? See the remark about quasi-projective.

Comment: @Alex First of all, thank you for the great answer. To get better understanding, I would like to understand one concrete example. Can you explain how to compute the Hodge structure of an elliptic curve via covering of $\mathbb{P}^1$? First we remove 4 points from $\mathbb{P}^1$ and...

Comment: This is a kind of examples I want to compute. I need mixed Hodge structure because of non-compactness, not singularity or anything.

Comment: @Cihan: Probably, I should clarify that it's not exactly the Hodge structure that we're computing but the Hodge spaces: you don't get their position w.r.t. the integral lattice. With this said, why do you want to compute something that's known and can be done much easier? Anyway, if you have to, it's easier to do the ramified covering directly. The bundle $\mathcal{L}$ is $\mathcal{O}(2)$ (in general, $1/n$-th of the ramification locus), and in the formulas above the ramification should be taken into account (in your case, just subtracted from all $\mathcal{L}_i$ except $i=0$,

Comment: i.e., from $\mathcal{L}_0$). Check [MR0672621] or [MR1304394] for more details; your case of points in a curve is similar, but much easier of curves in surfaces done there.